# Tensorflow in Raspberry Pi - memory error

Tags: tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install tensorflow in raspberry pi 4 with the next command:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

The next error occurs:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl (79.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 79.6MB 8.8MB/s 
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 338, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 836, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 677, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 600, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 489, in unzip_file
    data = zip.read(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1429, in read
    return fp.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 885, in read
    buf += self._read1(self.MAX_N)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 975, in _read1
    data = self._decompressor.decompress(data, n)
MemoryError
```

I have tried to install it with the next command that I've seen in the internet fixes the error, but it didn't.

```
pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow
```

Any clue on what could I do??

Thanks in advance.